# How to get the first dollar value from the text retrieved from the plain body from a Gmail email body

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Gmail Google App script. How do I retrieve the dollar values from the email plain body?

```
  const messageFortisBC = GmailApp.search('from:(gas.customerservice@fortisbc.com) AND has:attachment AND newer_than:7d')[0].getMessages()[0];
  const forwardedPlainMessageFortisBC = messageFortisBC.getPlainBody();

  const messageBCHydro  = GmailApp.search('from:(notifications@bchydro.com) AND subject:bill AND newer_than:7d')[0].getMessages()[0];
  const forwardedPlainMessageBCHydro = messageBCHydro.getPlainBody();
```

Example of input values for variable forwardedPlainMessageFortisBC. This value is partial and at the beginning of the text:

[image: Image of getPlainBody for messageFortisBC]

Example of input values for variable forwardedPlainMessageBCHydro. This value is partial and somewhere half way of the text:

Your pre-authorized payment of $246.96

I have tried the match and search methods for strings. They returned -1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing image and `Your pre-authorized payment of $246.96`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: There is no relationship between them. I’m trying to get dollar values or floats from both plain email bodies.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that there are many ways to answer this question.

This is via Regex.

```
var regex = new RegExp(/[\$](\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)/gm)

const forwardedPlainMessageFortisBC = messageFortisBC.getPlainBody()
var valueFortis = regex.exec(forwardedPlainMessageFortisBC)
Logger.log(valueFortis[0]) 

const forwardedPlainMessageBCHydro = messageBCHydro.getPlainBody();
var valueHYDRO = regex.exec(forwardedPlainMessageFortisBC)
Logger.log(valueHYDRO[0])
```

---

**Sample input/output**

[image: hydro]